# Ecto: How to update all records with a different random number

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have a table in postgresql and i want to update the value of column "points" for all the records with a random number. In other languages we could loop over all the db records but how can i do it with ecto? I tried this:

```
 Repo.all(from u in User, update: User.changeset(u, %{points: :rand.uniform(100)}))
```

but it outputs the following error:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/hello_remote/user.ex ==
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) malformed update `User.changeset(u, %{points: :rand.uniform(100)})` in query expression, expected a keyword list with set/push/pop as keys with field-value pairs as values
expanding macro: Ecto.Query.update/3
lib/hello_remote/user.ex:30: HelloRemote.User.update_points/0
expanding macro: Ecto.Query.from/2
lib/hello_remote/user.ex:30: HelloRemote.User.update_points/0
(elixir 1.10.4) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:304: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7
```

I've also tried this:

```
from(u in User)
|> Repo.update_all(set: [points: Enum.random(0..100)])
```

but it updates all the records with the same value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [fragment/1](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) with [update_all/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update_all/3), calling a PostgreSQL function to calculate the random values, for example:

```
update(User, set: [points: fragment("floor(random()*100)")])
|> Repo.update_all([])
```

Comment: can you please help me in this problem too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183075/add-interval-to-timestamp-using-ecto-fragments

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible with the `update_all` function. The function was created to update many rows with the same value.

You can create a loop and update each record separately, it's not nice but a working solution.

```
User
|> Repo.all()
|> Enum.each(fn user -> update_user(user) end)

def update_user(user) do
  user 
  |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(%{"points" => Enum.random(0..100)}, [:points])
  |> Repo.update!()
end
```

If you would like to do it one call you can construct a raw SQL query and use that.